# OpenGL rotation in 2D

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, 2d

I have a simple OpenGL application, which displays a line. I store `x1, y1, x2` and `y2` in global variables.

The rotation function uses the `feedback` functionality, discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277519/opengl-retrieve-raw-vertex-and-index-buffer-from-displayed-objects-in-opengl) and the translation to origin method, suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442743/opengl-es-rotating-3d-model-around-itself). It's intended to rotate a line around it's center.

Here's the code:

```
void rotate( float theta )
{

    GLfloat* buff = new GLfloat[5];
    glFeedbackBuffer( 5, GL_2D, buff );
    glRenderMode( GL_FEEDBACK );

    int center_x = x1 + ( x2 - x1 )/2;
    int center_y = y1 + ( y2 - y1 )/2;

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef( -center_x, -center_y, 0 );
        glRotatef( theta, 0, 0, 1 );
        glTranslatef( center_x, center_y, 0 );
        line();
    glPopMatrix();

    x1 = (int)buff[1];
    y1 = (int)buff[2];
    x2 = (int)buff[3];
    y2 = (int)buff[4];

    delete[] buff;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

However, the two translations seem to have little effect - the line still rotates around the lower-left corner of the window. In addition, the line gets clipped if it doesn't fit on the visible surface ( this doesn't happen with the translations commented out - the line simply refuses to move if it would fall outside the visible surface ).

Why doesn't this code work ? How do I rotate a line around it's center ( or any arbitrary point ) in 2D ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like you're translating in the wrong direction and the origin is being placed outside your viewport in the lower-left. You want to move the origin to the point you want to translate around--so if the origin is in the lower-left, you need to translate +center_x, +center_y. Rotate, translate back (-center_x, -center_y), then draw.

Comment: Indeed, now it works, thanks ! However, as it rotates, the line slowly moves towards the lower-left corner of the window; can this be avoided ?

Comment: You have two different centers to deal with: the center of the viewport and the midpoint of the line. I assume that you want the midpoint of the line centered in the viewport. So what you really want to do is translate to the center of the viewport, rotate, and draw your line relative to the translated origin (that is, a line whose midpoint is 0,0).

Comment: ok, but there's a problem when the new coordinates ( resulting from the translations + rotation ) fall outside the visible area. If this is the case, the feedback buffer will contain only the visible points. When I rotate back, the line is clipped - and I would like to get my line back intact.